# macro: does #define a(b) ({... c;}) means a(b) returns c?

Tags: c, linux-kernel

I have this code in linux kernel:

```
#define task_cred_xxx(task, xxx)                        
({                                                      
    __typeof__(((struct cred *)NULL)->xxx) ___val;  
    rcu_read_lock();                               
    ___val = __task_cred((task))->xxx;              
    rcu_read_unlock();                              
    ___val;                                         
})
```

I never saw macro defined like this before, does that mean this is task_cred_xxx(task, xxx) returns ___val?

Thanks!

Comment: Also, `((struct cred *)NULL)->xxx` is (I think) undefined behavior.

Comment: @ChrisLutz: Normally it is, but since the linux kernel targets only gcc, and gcc allows it, it's accepted.

Comment: @Chris Lutz: As long as only type or size of such expressions are needed, this is OK (at least for GCC), the expressions themselves are never evaluated. Take a look at the implementation of commonly used `container_of` macro in `<linux/kernel.h>` for another example of this trick.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Correct. It will return `___val`. However, block expressions like these are a GNU extension and isn't actually part of the C standard.

http://www.toofishes.net/blog/gcc-compound-statement-expressions/