# Can some one please find the reason for the error "a value of type "void" cannot be assigned to an entity of type "int" " in VScode?

Tags: c, visual-studio-code, intellisense

The code is as follows:

```
ssize_t readline(int fd, void *buf, size_t maxlen)
{
    char c;
    char * bufp=buf;
    int n;
    
    for(n = 0; n < maxlen - 1; n++)
    {
        int kk;
        if((kk = read_or_die(fd, &c, 1)) == 1) // **Intellisense throws error here**
        {
            *bufp++ = c; 
            if(c == '\n')
            break;               
        }

        else if (kk == 0)
        {
            if(n == 0) 
                return 0;

            else
                break;  
        }

        else
            return -1;

    }
    bufp = '\0';
    return n;


}
```

The definition of the function read_or_die is defined as follows:

```
#define read_or_die(fd, buf, count) \
    ({ssize_t rc = read(fd, buf, count); assert(rc >= 0); rc: })
```

From this link [Can someone please explain this macro definition?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64040245/can-someone-please-explain-this-macro-definition)  I understood that `rc` is returned from `read_or_die ()`. Clearly, `rc` is of type `ssize_t` not void.

Why does VScode intellisense throw this error at `if((kk = read_or_die(fd, &c, 1)) == 1)`   ?

[image]

Comment: Do you really have a `:` at the end?

Comment: I'd make ` read_or_die` a function in the first place. Making it a macro offers absolutely no advantage.

Comment: @Jabberwocky I need to call it multiple number of times. It becomes an overhead, if we use function due to function calls.

Comment: @KrishnaKanthYenumula no, it won't. The bottleneck is `read`.

Comment: When I changed the colon to a semicolon, this compiled for me

Comment: @klutt  Thank you. I did not check the colon at the end. My mistake.  Adding semi-colon worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding semicolon at the end of the macro is the solution.

```
#define read_or_die(fd, buf, count) \
    ({ssize_t rc = read(fd, buf, count); assert(rc >= 0); rc; })
```